# How to use AddHttpClient in .NET 6 Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0, worker

Is there an alternative way to add the "AddHttpClient()" setting in the .NET 6 Worker Service template?

In Minimal APIs for example we have available:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

In the Worker Service template is not:

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install matching version of [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/6.0.0) nuget (for .NET 6 `6.0.0` should be fine) and [`HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) will become available for your project.